# How do I specify width of post content for permalink pages on Tumblr?

Tags: css, tumblr

My Tumblr theme allows me to customize the width of posts on the main page. I chose 700 px.

However, when I got to the permalink page for an individual post, the content is wider.

I would like to alter the CSS for permalink pages so that the content width is 700 px. I have looked under the "permalinkpage" section of the CSS, but I cannot figure out how to alter the width. (I have no training in CSS--apologies if this question is dumb.)

CSS for permalinkpage section of my theme's CSS below. Please let me know if I'm looking in the wrong place. You can see that I have changed the only "width" to 700px, which did nothing.

```
<title>
    {Title}{block:PermalinkPage}{block:PostSummary} — {PostSummary}{/block:PostSummary}{/block:PermalinkPage}
</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=700px">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}" />
<link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon/72.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{favicon}">
<meta name="theme-color" content="{AccentColor}">
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change meta tag like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=700"> //px is removed
```

Or you can use css style property max-width

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope this helps you to solve!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Bojan. Can you please clarify where the "body" tag should go, in the code for the permalinkpage?